# How-to suppress constraint and layout warnings in Xcode 5 on a storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, autolayout

is there any flag to suppress Ambiguous Layout or Misplaced views for storyboards in Xcode 5.

I am adding the constraints in code and am just using the views in Interfacebuilder as dummies.

I do not want to apply Xcode Resolve auto layout issues since I am happy how the views appear visually in Interfacebuilder?

Comment: you could add constraints and mark them as placeholders, but I agree a lot of work for something so small

Comment: `Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options`, have an option to disable all warnings, but there is no options for individual files or kind of warnings AFAIK.

Comment: I tried it but even setting NO to warnings has no effect on layout constraints...

Comment: well after restarting my computer and setting nterface Builder XIB Compiler - Options WARNINGS Flag = NO the storyboard warnings disappeared thanks Volker and A-Live

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select Project Build Settings ->
Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options ->
Show Warnings -> set to "NO"

Note that if you wish to clear existing warnings you can clean your project using `Shift+⌘+k`

Comment: This turns off all IB warnings, not just constraint and layout ones, and that's suboptimal.

Comment: I have this option set to no, but still getting stupid warnings f.e. saying that a views frame will be different at runtime (which I can fix, but simply opening IB will bring it back...)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to completely restart Xcode for the

```
Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options 
WARNINGS Flag = NO
```

to be considered!