# Attribute unavailable warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I'm updating my app to support iOS 11 and I added the large titles options in the interface builder. Now I'm getting these "Attribute unavailable - prefers large titles before iOS 11.0" warnings.

I know I can set the options programmatically, but that's causing some other problems, so I was hoping I could keep it at the storyboard and just ignore the warnings. If the options aren't available that's fine, just don't use them. Is there a way to do that?

I know there are other questions asking the same thing, but they're pretty old and the answers end up working around it instead of really dealing with the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, your app is probably targeting iOS <11 so the attribute will not be used for earlier versions.

Have you tested your app in iOS 11 and 10 ?

Solutions:

- Disable that feature
- Set it in code using `if #available` (Best option if you want to maintain compatibility with earlier iOS versions and use that feature)
- Set the target of your project to iOS 11
- [Suppress all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37024724/2124535) / [Storyboard files only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139086/2124535) (Not recommended)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't want to keep getting those warnings.

Comment: I have tested on both, it works fine, it's just the warnings that are bugging me.

Comment: That's what I meant with "I know I can set the options programmatically"… but I was hoping I could deal with the warning itself.

Comment: You can't hide that specific warning, check the last link

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Those warnings about misplaced stuff are really annoying. I'll consider that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP does not state whether Swift or Objective-C is being used, I will post both versions.

- Swift 2.0+: `if #available(iOS 11, *) {}`
- Obj-C: `if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {}`

Courtesy of [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)

As a side note I was able to suppress the specific warning with

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunguarded-availability"
... your code here ...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Not recommending that - but as a quick fix it works.